# Как из QLineEdit получить значение integer? PyQt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, pyqt5, pyqt

Суть вопроса в заголовке.

При получении при помощи `.text` или `.toPlainText`, и попытке переделать его в `integer` при помощи `int(variable)`, UI крашится.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У `QLineEdit` есть только `.text()`, а `.toPlainText()` это к `QTextEdit` и `QPlainTextEdit`.

Кроме того, если в `int(...)` будет передано, что-то отличное от числового значения, будет исключение, которое если не ловить, сломает приложение.

Пример (Замените `'123'`, например на `'123,'` и получите ошибку):

```
from PyQt5.Qt import QLineEdit, QApplication

app = QApplication([])

line_edit = QLineEdit('123')
value = line_edit.text()
print(value)       # "123"
print(int(value))  # 123
```

---

**PS.** Чтобы поймать исключение в слотах Qt, добавьте код:

```
def log_uncaught_exceptions(ex_cls, ex, tb):
    text = '{}: {}:\n'.format(ex_cls.__name__, ex)
    import traceback
    text += ''.join(traceback.format_tb(tb))

    print(text)
    QMessageBox.critical(None, 'Error', text)
    quit()


import sys
sys.excepthook = log_uncaught_exceptions
```

---

**PPS.** а зачем вам `QLineEdit`? Может быть, лучше использовать `QSpinBox`? У `QSpinBox` есть метод `.value()` которое вернет `int`

---

**PPPS.** добавлю пример проверки значения строки при конвертации в число:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication, QLineEdit, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout, QMessageBox


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.line_edit = QLineEdit('123')
        self.button_check = QPushButton('Проверить число!')
        self.button_check.clicked.connect(self._on_check)

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.line_edit)
        layout.addWidget(self.button_check)

        self.setLayout(layout)

    def _on_check(self):
        text = self.line_edit.text()

        try:
            value = int(text)
            QMessageBox.information(self, 'Информация', 'Введено число: "{}"'.format(value))

        except ValueError:
            QMessageBox.warning(self, 'Внимание', 'Введено невалидное число: "{}"'.format(text))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])

    mw = Window()
    mw.show()

    app.exec()
```

Comment: Даже если вводится числовое значение, всё равно ломается :).

Comment: Какая ошибка? И добавьте в вопрос минимальный пример кода с вашей ошибкой

Comment: Но спасибо, сработало.

Comment: Просто крашилось, когда пытался перевести str в int

Comment: @AgeofCreations, в таких случаях сделайте проверку и уведомление, например `try: value = int(value_str)` `except ValueError as e: QMessageBox.critical(None, 'Error', "Введено невалидное число '{}'".format(value_str))`

Answer (score 0):

Я также предполагаю, что лучше использовать QSpinBox.

Но если все таки надо преобразовать 'str' в 'int', то это можно сделать так:

```
import re

>>> string = " Это какая-то строка 123 возможно с цифрами 4567"
>>> int("0"+"".join(list(map(str, re.findall(r'\d+', string)))))
1234567
>>> 
>>> string = "12345"
>>> int("0"+"".join(list(map(str, re.findall(r'\d+', string)))))
12345
>>> 
>>> string = ""
>>> int("0"+"".join(list(map(str, re.findall(r'\d+', string)))))
0
>>> 
>>> string = "БлаБлаБла"
>>> int("0"+"".join(list(map(str, re.findall(r'\d+', string)))))
0
>>> 
>>> string = "   "
>>> int("0"+"".join(list(map(str, re.findall(r'\d+', string)))))
0
```